# Object.create(myObj) when myObj contains dictionaries

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an object to be used as a prototype for other objects. This object contains primitives as well as a series of dictionaries. My problem is that when the dictionary properties are edited through one of the object's methods, it edits the dictionary in the object prototype, instead of the dictionary in the specific object instance.

For example:

```
const protoObj= {
  myPrim: false,
  myDict: {},
  changePrim: function(val) {
    this.myPrim = val;
  },
  addToDict: function(val) {
    this.myDict[val] = val;
  }
};

const myObj2 = Object.create(protoObj);
myObj2.changePrim(true);
myObj2.addToDict("test");
const myObj3 = Object.create(protoObj);
```

At this point `myObj2.myPrim` is true, and `myObj3.myPrim` is false. But the addToDict method added the "test" entry to the myDict of the prototype object, so now myDict has been essentially modified for both myObj2 and myObj3.

[image]

How could I make it such that actions on the dictionary member only affect the specific object instance?

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a function that returns an object with the desired properties (created anew every time the function creates a new object):

```js
const makeObj = () => {
  const protoObj = {
    myPrim: false,
    myDict: {},
    changePrim: function(val) {
      this.myPrim = val;
    },
    addToDict: function(val) {
      this.myDict[val] = val;
    }
  };
  return Object.create(protoObj);
}

const myObj2 = makeObj();
myObj2.changePrim(true);
myObj2.addToDict("test");
const myObj3 = makeObj();
console.log(myObj3.myDict);
```

Comment: Looks good but is there any benefit to `Object.create` here?

Comment: It sounded like OP wanted it for some reason, but yeah, it's not doing anything. @Alex Unless you're sure you need the `Object.create` for something in particular, you can remove it entirely.

Comment: I don't need it for something specific. It was just something I came across to create a custom object. I used it mostly as it seemed familiar to how you'd create objects in other languages (Java, Python, etc).

Comment: Do you know the reason it doesn't work with Object.create()?

Comment: @AlexB Why would it? I don't understand the purpose of the `Object.create`. Using it means that the internal prototype of the created object points to a different object. If different instances mutate the same shared internal prototype all objects have, then all objects will see the changes.

Comment: I get that for this particular use case it might not be the best approach, but I was just wondering what the reason for the this.myPrim assignment working differently than this.myDict when done from inside the method. In the case of the primitive it doesn't change the prototype, but in the case of dictionary it does modify the prototype?

Comment: @AlexB When you assign to a property, if the first matching property found in the object's prototype chain is a *data property*, the new value is assigned to the *instance* even though the property might have been found higher up. Yeah, it's kinda weird. `this.myPrim = val` assigns `val` to an own property of `this`; it doesn't overwrite what's on the prototype.